# how to send datagridview contents to email by c#

Tags: c#, email, datagridview

This is my code to send datagridview contents to email It works, but the names of the columns is not up to E-mail;
What is your advice??

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "********");

        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("email@gmail.com");
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Subject = "any";

        string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>"; ;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in itemDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            mailBody += "<tr>";
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                mailBody += "<td>" + cell.Value + "</td>";
            }
            {
                mailBody += "</tr>";
            }
        }
        mailBody += "</table>";

        mail.Body = mailBody;
        client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the columns of the `GridView` to create the first `<tr>` of your `<table>`. Before your first `foreach` loop you could put this code snippet.

```
mailBody += "<tr>";
foreach (DataControlField col in itemDataGridView.Columns)
{
    mailBody += "<td>" + col.HeaderText + "</td>";
}
mailBody += "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

the informations that you are looking for aren't in `itemDataGridView.Rows`.
to get columns name you should check for `dataGridView.Columns[index].Name`

in your case you should cycle it

```
foreach (DataControlField column in itemDataGridView.Columns)
    {
           //use column.HeaderText or column.Name
    }
```

`HeaderText` Gets the caption text on the column's header cel
`Name` Gets  the name of the column